# Haml Coffee ie8 error

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript, hamlc

I'm currently using [haml_coffee_assets](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets) on a project with backbone. All browsers seem to work quite well........ except IE8.

Error I receive: `Expected ']' in regular expression`

the line it refers to is the following:

```
 HAML.findAndPreserve = function(text) {
      var tags;
      tags = 'textarea,pre'.split(',').join('|');
      // **THE LINE BELOW** 
      return text = text.replace(RegExp("<(" + tags + ")>([^]*?)<\\/\\1>", "g"), function(str, tag, content) {
        return "<" + tag + ">" + (window.HAML.preserve(content)) + "</" + tag + ">";
      });
    };
```

It is preventing the entire page from compiling on load. The data-bound divs are completely empty, but all other static elements are loading fine.

Comment: Issue on haml_coffee_assets https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets/issues/114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RegExp in question is there to preserve newlines in certain tags by converting them to its HTML entity format, so

```
<pre>Bar
Baz</pre>
```

becomes

```
<pre>Bar&#x000A;Baz</pre>
```

Since you cannot make the dot match newlines in JavaScript, you can use an empty negotiated character class to match everything. Since we're in the browser, you can easily overwrite `HAML.findAndPreserve` to test alternative approaches. I have no problems changing it for IE8, but I refuse to install a VM just to test it :-)

An alternative to `[^]` is `[\s\S]` and I've successfully tested it in Node.js by changing the corresponding code in [Haml Coffee](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee/blob/master/src/haml-coffee.coffee#L476) and all specs are passing fine. Can you please try it in IE8 and report if that is valid and works? Thank you!